# How do I help Stack Exchange websites with translation?

Tags: support, languages, localization

I want to contribute to the community by translating various pages (or questions) into Hindi. Please advise.

Comment: How would this help?

Comment: Isn't it a potential way of helping the community? Someone said that SE can be helped in various ways and included that translation is a good thing?

Comment: Related to [Is English required on Stack Overflow?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy) also check  [Non-English Question Policy](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy) blog post. Exceptions are language specific Stack Overflow sites (like Portuguese) with some more incoming ones that are waiting to open in close beta.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two distinct sets of translations that can be done. One is a translation of the user interface, and the other is a translation of the questions and answers themselves.

It is important to understand that Stack Exchange is focused on communities and not creating content *per-se*: we, as a company, focus on creating great communities and give them the best tools to create great content in turn. The reason for this becomes most evident when you realize that sites need a healthy community for voting, ergo improving the signal-to-noise ratio, and for maintaining the existing content. Simply assembling a large amount of translated content would create a dead site, and we are not interested in that.

As such, the translation of questions and answers is of no great interest to us, but the translation of the user interface certainly is. Communities form around communication, culture and language - eventually also around UI language.

So, we are very interested in creating new communities. We can ask: would a Hindi-based programmer community work and be able to be self sustaining?

We have a proven tool to measure that: Area51. It is a site where users can suggest ideas for communities, where those ideas are developed and where a proto-community can form.

For example, when we launched Portuguese there was a committed community of 400 people that we worked with. Whilst they did not translate the bulk of the UI, their contribution was extremely important, especially for tricky parts like badge names. They also decided when translations were not adequate and implemented improvements.

Therefore, my first bit of advice is that you propose such a community on [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), promote it, and get at least 200 committers.

Once we have a viable proposal, we will consider creating a site. Differently from specific topic sites in English, creating a non-English site requires that we hire a Community Manager who is fluent in the language we consider, besides translating the UI. This limits the number of different languages we can support and more importantly, represents a significant time constraint because finding the right person generally proves quite complicated.

On the other hand, translating the site in a new language can be as easy as paying a translation company and waiting a month for the translated strings to come in.

So, my second bit of advice is: once we post a job ad for a Hindi CM, you could consider applying for this position. This will give you a huge influence is how the site is created and translated.

Finally, *once the private beta launches* there will be plenty of opportunities to contribute translations, of course, as part of the Hindi community.

It takes a lot of steps to get something like a Hindi Stack Overflow launched - these steps are a necessary precondition to ensure the success of such a community. You can certainly help us every step of the way.

Comment: Sure and thanks! I'll do that! I just thought that maybe the community needed help with questions' translations. My fault, no harm done. I'll do what you said. Thanks again.